# How to add value of previous array element to current element

Tags: c#, arrays

For each element in the array,which is filled with random integers, I need to add value of previous element to it's current element.

This is my code:

```
   class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int[] numbers = new int[10];
            Random generator = new Random();
            for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Length; i++)
            {
                numbers[i] = generator.Next(0, 100);
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Length; i++)
            {
                Console.Write("{0} ", numbers[i]);
            }
            Console.WriteLine();

            for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Length+1; i++)
            {
                Console.Write("{0} ", numbers[i]);
                numbers[i + 1] += numbers[i];
            }
```

*(from comment)* It doesn't work correctly. I have made some changes, but I still get IndexOutOfRangeException after the last value. It must be 10 random values as input and 10 for output. But the code works correctly only to 9 values output.

Comment: Does you code work? Does it produce compile time errors? Are you looking for alternative approach? Are there any restrictions on solution? - it is really hard to see what *kind* of help you are looking for.

Comment: it doesn't work correctly. I have made some changes, but I still get IndexOutOfRangeException after the last value. It mut be 10 random values as input and 10 for output. But the code works correctly only to 9 values output.

Comment: Milenita, please make sure to update post directly instead/in addition to  answering to comment. This way question becomes better (and as side effect get bumped as "newly edited" so more people can see it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a bug in your final loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Length + 1; i++)
    numbers[i + 1] += numbers[i];
```

This will cause `numbers[i + 1]` to throw an `IndexOutOfRangeException` for the last two iterations. Instead, use the following to stop at the last element:

```
for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Length - 1; i++)
    numbers[i + 1] += numbers[i];
```

Another potential issue is that each element would already have been summed with its predecessor(s) by the time it's read to update its successor. If you only want to add the value of the immediate predecessor, invert the flow of your loop:

```
for (int i = numbers.Length - 1; i > 0; i--)
    numbers[i] += numbers[i - 1];
```

**Edit**: If you want to output the new values in your array as part of the same loop, you can adapt it like so:

```
for (int i = numbers.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    if (i > 0)
        numbers[i] += numbers[i - 1];
    Console.Write("{0} ", numbers[i]);
}
```

Note that the first number (at index 0) does not have its value changed (as there is no predecessor to add to it); it is merely printed with its old value.

Comment: Only now the output elements are 9 not 10. How can do it without throw me exception IndexOutOfRange?

Comment: @Milenita: Check final edit.